# Apache CollectionUtil filter list contains enum list words

Tags: java, apache, arraylist, filter, enums

i'm really new in Java. I would like to make something for a REST services.
I have an array list of an object contains data, i would like to remove all object that don't match a criteria based on enum.
I get some sample with the Apache CollectionUtils and filter. but all i found is related to an equals value.

at the moment, this is the code i've done

```
    MyObjectFiltered.addAll(ListedMyObject);

    CollectionUtils.filter(MyObjectFiltered, new Predicate() {

        @Override
        public boolean evaluate(Object object) {
            boolean boolFound = false;

            for(String EnumItem : EnumAsList)
            {
                boolFound = ((MyObjectModel) object).getValue() == EnumItem ;
            }
            return boolFound;
        }
    });
```

I know that's not the way to do what i want but i can't figure how i can do it. Do you guys have any suggestion i can search to reach my goal?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you simply want to remove objects from the list that don't match a certain Enum? You won't need an external library for something that simple, Java 8's lambdas can do that for you.

You just need something along the lines of `MyObjectFiltered.removeIf(object -> !EnumAsList.contains(object.getValue());`

Basically that means remove the object from my list if the enums list does not contain it.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the java stream API is for. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html

```
var filteredList = MyObjectFiltered
    .stream()
    .filter(obj -> EnumList.contains(obj.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, i will try this way!